# Using memcpy to move block headers to the beginning of blocks in a memory free store -- Is it possible?

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, memcpy

I'm currently learning about Dynamic Memory Allocation, and attempting to code my own dynamic memory allocator using the C language.

I've been studying with the original K&R book, and their unrestricted dynamic allocator is very interesting with one exception: I'm unable to find a way to get block headers into the free store memory allocated via sbrk(). Instead of placing the union header into the store via K&R's version, would it be possible to use memcpy to manually copy a union header to the end+1 of the previous block, and point to it via prevblock->next?

Here is K & R's example implementation of malloc:

```
static Header base; /* empty list to get started */
static Header *freep = NULL; /* ptr to last block used */

/* malloc: general-purpose storage allocator */
void *malloc(unsigned nbytes)
{
   Header *p, *prevp;
   Header *morecore(unsigned);
   unsigned nunits;

   nunits = (nbytes+sizeof(Header)-1)/sizeof(header) + 1;

   if ((prevp = freep) == NULL) { /* no free list yet */
      base.s.ptr = freeptr = prevptr = &base;
      base.s.size = 0;
   }

   for (p = prevp->s.ptr; ; prevp = p, p = p->s.ptr) {
      if (p->s.size >= nunits) { /* big enough */
        if (p->s.size == nunits) /* exactly */
           prevp->s.ptr = p->s.ptr;
        else { /* allocate tail end */
           p->s.size -= nunits;
           p += p->s.size;
           p->s.size = nunits
             }
        freep = prevp;
        return (void *)(p+1);
      }

      if (p == freep) /* wrapped around free list */
         if ((p = morecore(nunits)) == NULL)
             return NULL; /* none left */
      }
}

#define NALLOC 1024 /* minimum #units to request */
/* morecore: ask system for more memory */
static Header *morecore(unsigned nu)
{

  char *cp, *sbrk(int);
  Header *up;

  if (nu < NALLOC)
    nu = NALLOC;

  cp = sbrk(nu * sizeof(Header));

  if (cp == (char *) -1) /* no space at all */
    return NULL;

  up = (Header *) cp;
  up->s.size = nu;
  free((void *)(up+1));

  return freep;
}

/* free: put block ap in free list */
void free(void *ap) {
  Header *bp, *p;
  bp = (Header *)ap - 1; /* point to block header */
  for (p = freep; !(bp > p && bp < p->s.ptr); p = p->s.ptr)
    if (p >= p->s.ptr && (bp > p || bp < p->s.ptr))
      break; /* freed block at start or end of arena */
  if (bp + bp->size == p->s.ptr) {
    bp->s.size += p->s.ptr->s.size;
    bp->s.ptr = p->s.ptr->s.ptr;
  } else
      bp->s.ptr = p->s.ptr;

  if (p + p->size == bp) {
    p->s.size += bp->s.size;
    p->s.ptr = bp->s.ptr;
  } else
    p->s.ptr = bp;
  freep = p;
}
```

I understand that the *free* function actually places new blocks into the free store, and that things could be achieved this way. However, instead of using free to put new blocks (new block *headers*) into the free store at the correct places, would it be possible to implement this ability into malloc itself via memcpy? Creating the header within malloc, using memcpy to copy the header to the end+1 of the last block or wherever the block fits, and then freeing the original header?

Comment: Perhaps you could give some examples of what you have in mind.  As it stands, this question is incomprehensible to anyone who doesn't have the book open in front of them.

Comment: Alright, I'll go ahead and edit that question with the K & R Allocator code